# TableLayout when i use different Columns in Different rows

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, tablelayout

I Use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/) example (table layout) and in the example its seems to work fine but in mine project i have an extra table cell . I use VS 2013 and Xamrin-Android (latest version) and i deploy on API 21 (android 5.0.1). What is the problem?

Here is the code that wont work on me

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:shrinkColumns="*" 
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:background="#ffffff"> 

    <!-- Row 1 with single column -->
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp" android:text="Row 1"  android:layout_span="3"
            android:padding="18dip" android:background="#b0b0b0"
            android:textColor="#000"/>  
    </TableRow>  

    <!-- Row 2 with 3 columns -->
    <TableRow 
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 column 1"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#dcdcdc"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>  
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 column 2"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#d3d3d3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 2 column 3"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#cac9c9"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>
    </TableRow> 

    <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->
    <TableRow 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 3 column 1"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#b0b0b0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:text="Row 3 column 2"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#a09f9f"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="20dip" android:gravity="center"/>  
    </TableRow>  

</TableLayout>
```

And the Result on me
[image: result]

Comment: this worked for me as well but you can try this statement maybe it solves your problem:
add the following to your 3rd table row
android:layout_weight="2"

Comment: I tested your xml and it works fine for me. Btw don't use the same id for all your TextViews

Comment: @Rami Where you tested? on phone or  visual studio or android studio? And i know about ids this is dummy project :)

Comment: AndroidStudio preview and Galaxy S3 (real device)

Comment: @Rami Maybe its Xamarin problem. In Android Studio the preview seems ok? thanks fro your help

Comment: Yep, it's ok in AndroidStudio... maybe it's related to Xamarin, try to run your code in real device or emulator from Xamarin and see if you still have this extra column

Comment: @Rami Yes it worked but this is serious problem. I cant design and think how it look on the device all the time :/ P.S how i close this question?

Comment: Yes, it 'll be boring. For your question, you can just answer it, see this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on Visual Studio designer the preview didn't work property . When I test it on real device it worked. Thanks to @Rami on the comments i figured out.